# difference between defining controller inside directive or simple controller

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angularjs.I have a question while defining controller in angularjs.In Angular we can define controller like:

```
app.controller('demo', function (){

})
```

or in directive we can define

```
.directive('component', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        require: '^screen',
        controller: function($scope) {
            this.componentFunction = function() {
                $scope.screenCtrl.doSomethingScreeny();
            }
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, screenCtrl) {
            scope.screenCtrl = screenCtrl
        }
    }
})
```

what is the difference between both controllers.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between these two implementations is which scope the controller has access to. Your "demo" controller has access to the scope where it is assigned, like in a route or DOM element for instance. The directive controller only has access to your directive.

Other than the scope these two controllers have access to, there's no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Difference is between the implementations

Normal controller will be attached to DOM in static way whereas controller in directive can be added dynamically where need occurs controller in directive also provides isolated scope of elements that will be binded to that specific  part of DOM where controller has been implemented.